# Optimization of constructor in the class

Tags: ruby

How to use hash, i can write this class better?

```
class Bank
    def initialize(name, city, country, max_credit_value, min_credit_value, credit_time)
        @name = name
        @coordinates = coordBainates
        @country = country
        @max_credit_value = max_credit_value
        @min_credit_value = min_credit_value
        @interest_rate = interest_rate
        @credit_time = credit_time 
    end
end
```

Perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: It depends of the definition of *"better"*. Your current code expresses the intention, everything is clear. Keep it this way.

Comment: Where is `coordBainates` and `interest_rate` coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the arguments in an array so you don't have to keep everything in sync. Use a little bit of metaprogramming to get them into instance variables:

```
class Bank
  def initialize opts={}
    keys = %i{name coordinates country max_credit_value min_credit_value interest_rate credit_time}
    raise ArgumentError, "invalid options: expected #{keys}, got #{opts.keys}" unless keys.sort == opts.keys.sort
    keys.each { |key| instance_variable_set "@#{key}", opts[key] }
  end
end
```

and then initialize with

```
Bank.new name: "Foobar", coordinates: [2, 5], country: "US", etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aim for shortest code and your constructor code has only assignments then maybe this is *better*

```
class Bank < Struct.new(:name, :city, :country, :max_credit_value, :min_credit_value, :credit_time)
end
```

Comment: Except don't _inherit_ from Struct. Just `Bank = Struct.new(:name, ...`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev why you don't recommend inheritance in this case?

Comment: It adds nothing. Except one extra level of inheritance. Also is longer to type. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯